# CarrotGarden Eclipse Plugin for Maven SCR fails to install

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I've imported a large OSGI project into Eclipse JEE Kepler.  M2E reports  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem with the `org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr` plugin.

When I try to install carrotgardern scr plugin from the Marketplace I get the following error.  Is there another way to use the Maven SCR plugin from Eclipse?

Thanks

===============================================================================

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: CarrotGarden M2E SCR 2.0.1.201302272113 (com.carrotgarden.m2e.scr.feature.feature.group 2.0.1.201302272113)
  Missing requirement: CarrotGarden M2E SCR 2.0.1.201302272113 (com.carrotgarden.m2e.scr.plugin 2.0.1.201302272113) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.1.0,1.4.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CarrotGarden M2E SCR 2.0.1.201302272113 (com.carrotgarden.m2e.scr.feature.feature.group 2.0.1.201302272113)
    To: com.carrotgarden.m2e.scr.plugin [2.0.1.201302272113]
```

Comment: Seems like I'm the only other person in the known universe with exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Apparently CarrotGarden is not compatible with the latest version of M2E. You need to install an older version of M2E.

https://github.com/carrot-garden/carrot-eclipse/issues/3